# NavigationStack is not showing initial navigation path when presented in a sheet

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationstack

I want to present a view with a `NavigationStack` that has an initial path. This almost always works, but not when that view is presented as a sheet. Then, it only shows the root view of the `NavigationStack`.

Here is a fully working example:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State var isShowingSheet = false
    @State var isShowingFullscreenCover = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Sheet") {
                isShowingSheet = true
            }
            Button("Show Fullscreen Cover") {
                isShowingFullscreenCover = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet) {
            // Opens at the root (Showing the "Root" text below)
            PresentedView()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowingFullscreenCover) {
            // Opens with page "5", which is the top of the intially defined navigation stack from `path`
            PresentedView()
        }
    }
}

struct PresentedView: View {
    @State var path: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Text("Root")
                .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { number in
                    Text("\(number)")
                        .navigationTitle("\(number)")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Sheet presentation:

[image]

FullScreenCover presentation:

[image]

Is this a bug in `SwiftUI` or am I missing something? Is this intentional? Does anyone know a fix/workaround?

Answer (score 2):

To me this is a bug.

Here is a workaround setting the path in `.onAppear`. But watch the still different behavior of sheet and fullscreencover.

The strangest thing is that for sheet to work, the path has to be initially empty !?

```
struct PresentedView: View {
    @State var path: [Int] = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Text("Root")
                .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { number in
                    Text("\(number)")
                        .navigationTitle("\(number)")
                }
                .navigationTitle("Root")
        }
        .onAppear {
            path = [1,2,3,4,5]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that's kind of hilarious. Setting it in `.onAppear` makes it work fine in a `sheet`, but now the `fullScreenCover` opens at the root (and then animates a push animation) :D Yeah, it seems the path has to be initially empty for the sheet, which makes it seemingly impossible to have both `sheets` and `fullScreenCover` work at the same time with this workaround :/ Super strange, but appreciate your help!

Comment: Just to be sure, I submitted it as a bug: FB11946726

Comment: Currently the below code makes it seemingly impossible to have both sheets and fullScreenCover work at the same time, as well in my iOS 17 only app!

```.sheet(isPresented: $showDetailView) {
            NavigationStack {
                DetailView(isShowingBottomSheet: $isShowingBottomSheet)
                    .navigationTitle("Detail")
            }
        }```